# Execution flow on the host just after starting the kernel

Tags: opencl

I have several queries for which I need some clarifications.. Sorry if they seem to be very basic.

1. When we start the kernel using clEnqueueNDRangeKernel, what actually happens to the host code, does it wait for the kernel to complete or ..?
2. Say we have multiple kernels, what happens in this case? does it happen that if one of the kernel has completed, can the host retrieve results from that kernel while others are still doing the computations.
3. I was reading the OpenCL spec for clCreateBuffer ([link here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html)). Check the description of the flag CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR. For your convenience I have posted it here: 
   **"it indicates that the application wants the OpenCL implementation to use memory referenced by host_ptr as the storage bits for the memory object."**

I am not able to get what exactly they mean by "application" and "opencl implementation". Further it also says that **"OpenCL implementations are allowed to cache the buffer contents."**

Answer (score 1):

1. Kernel module is enqueued and executed asynchronously, clEnqueueNDRangeKernel returns immediately and host program continues execution. To make this call synchronous, wait for event from the last optional parameter, or call clFinish to wait for all queued commands.
2. Multiple kernels are executed sequentially in the same order as they enqueued, if they belong to the same command queue.
3. Application means your code running on the host. OpenCL implementation is a library implementing OpenCL interface. There are several OpenCL implementations, like AMD, NVidia etc.

OpenCL program contains three components: host code running in CPU, OpenCL library (implementation), and kernel modules running in GPU.

Comment: For point 2: in order execution is guaranteed unless the command queue is created with CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE.

Comment: Ok thanks. So if I have a clEnqueueReadBuffer after the NDRangeKernel and I haven't given any wait for event. Further clEnqueueReadBuffer is also asynchronous i.e. no wait for event specified. So in this case how will the clEnqueueReadBuffer execute.. does it start reading the data incrementally i.e. it reads the data that has been processed by the kernel and goes on similarly to read if any more data is processed and is made available by the kernel...  ??

Comment: For point 2: What would suffice for starting all the kernels simultaneously, having just separate command queues or all the context, program.. etc have to be separate for each kernel ?

Comment: Typically you enqueue several commands to the same command queue, and wait for last of them. clEnqueueReadBuffer reads the whole buffer to CPU before next enqueued command starts.

Comment: Several command queues make sense for unrelated tasks. One command queue may be used for consequent operations on some memory object, for example, image.